# variable is not getting assigned

Tags: c++

I got a small problem, i'm trying to do a calculation, in a quickway.

mf=1/n*x

so i wrote a small programm which should do that.
I'm using global variables:

```
float mf = NULL;
float xCalce = NULL;
int n = NULL;
vector<float> x = {-10.2, -8.0, 0.5, 5.9, 3.5, 22.7, 15.0, -1.8, -3.1, 7.7, 11.2, 7.9, -3.3,
                   -1.6, 15.3, 22.6, 3.6, 5.7, 2.0, -18.2, -27.5, 23.1, 18.1, 9.7, 25.8};
```

i calculate x from an vector of numbers and I'm using a forwhile loop

```
for (float xs : x) {
        sumX(xs);
    };
```

to send it to this function:

```
void sumX(float &x) 
{
    xCalce += x;
}
```

which works.

i want to do the same for mf, but i miss something because it's not saving to the global variable mf;

```
 void calcMf(float x, int n) {
   mf =(1/n)*(x);
}
```

When i call the debugger, n and x are correct but as I said before the value is not saved in mf?

Edit1: added the vector, everything else is described in the text
Edit2:added the main function

```
int main() {


    n = x.size();
    //

    for (float xs : x) {
        sumX(xs);
    };
    calcMf(xCalce,n);


    cout << "summ of x : " << xCalce << endl;
    cout << "mf: " << mf << endl;
    cout << n << endl;
}
```

Comment: `float mf = NULL;` most probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant.

Comment: Your post appears to be missing a [mcve]

Comment: And please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: ok, i thought it will get overwritten like in xCalc. Null is like void... so nothing is assigned?
@rest, only the vector was missing, but as i said this is working, main is calling the functions, what is missing?

Comment: Stop that. Don't assume that the feature of one language is like the feature of another language...go out an _verify_ if before you move forward with that assumption.

Comment: As for your problem, `1 / n` is an *integer* division. Unless `n == 1` then the result of it will be zero.

Comment: Problem was that n was an int, with float it's working.
even if mf = null, alltough i changed it to 0, I'm not perfect...
@Someprogrammerdude
Thanks!

CaptainObvlious
you are right, but right now I'm learning c++

Comment: _main is calling the functions, what is missing?_ no one can coyp and run aour code because **main is missing**.

Comment: I added the main function, can you please cancel the downvote... thats somehow annoying if you just downvote, but after the fix it's still the same.

Answer (score 1):

change n to float, and set the mf=null to 0;

Comment: Why should you change `n` to `float`? In this case `n` means _count of something_, leave it `int`. You could replace `1` with `1.0`, but in _computer math_ it is better (in most cases) to put division as the last operation, so we would have `1*x/n` and even better `mf=x/n;`. It is simpler and it works as intended. KISS.